# Exiv2 in 64-bit (or another EXIF writer)

Tags: .net, 64-bit, jpeg, exif, exiv2

I need a non-destructive way of adding EXIF tags to jpeg images from .NET code. So far I have found Exiv2 and the .NET wrapper Exiv2net that works well when adding or updating tags. However, my code needs to run on a 64-bit machine (and compiled for 64-bit due to other reasons) and it seems to me that the Exiv2 code only compiles in 32-bit.

I am therefore looking for either someone working on a 64-bit version of Exiv2 and Exiv2net or another toolkit entirely. Has anyone seen such a thing?

Btw, the BitmapMetadata from WPF removes EXIF tags when updating and will not work for my purposes.

Comment: My understanding is that the BitmapMetadata class *could* do it -- how are you calling it/what makes you say it's being "destructive"

Comment: BitmapMetadata most certainly can add entries but it removes others when doing so, e.g. some of the Maker notes.

Answer (score 0):

If you know your target system will have a Perl interpreter, you could bundle [exiftool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) and call it to do work on behalf of your app. You may even be able to [compile it into a standalone executable](http://web.archive.org/web/20080822004405/http://www.expertsrt.com/tutorials/Matt/perlPAR.html).

Comment: I want to reduce the number of dependencies so using Exiftool is not really an option in this situation. Exiv2net works for me - it just requires me to run the application in 32-bit even when running on 64-bit machines.